# Word document automatically changes font in number list

Tags: fonts, ms-word

When I download a Word document from the web, the number list changes font.
I am using Roboto, and my template on Speclink is in Roboto.
I download a Word document from Speclink, and when I open it up the number list font is in Times New Roman.

To change the font to Roboto, I have to File/Options/Advanced/Font Substitution and change it to Roboto for every document.
I have clicked Change Permanently, and updated my Normal.dotm template.
When I File/Options/Advanced/Font Substitution in my Normal.dotm template, it will not update, I get a message that all of the fonts have already been substituted.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to set the font name of the number list in a new open document, then you can write the code in the **ThisDocument**'s **Document_Open** event.
[image]

```vb
Private Sub Document_Open()
    Call Word_document_automatically_changes_font_in_number_list
    'Word_document_automatically_changes_font_in_number_list_All ' or this one
End Sub
```

Sorry, I don't install the font **Roboto**, you could try it by yourself. I've already tested in the other font.

```vb
Sub Word_document_automatically_changes_font_in_number_list()
    Dim lss As Word.Lists, ls As Word.List, lsf As Word.ListFormat, d As Document, ur As UndoRecord
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    Set lss = d.Lists
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "Word_document_automatically_changes_font_in_number_list"
    For Each ls In lss
        Set lsf = ls.Range.ListFormat
        'if lsf.List.Range.Font.Name<>"Roboto" then
        If lsf.List.Range.Font.Name <> "Calibri" Then
            'lsf.List.Range.Font.Name = "Roboto"
            lsf.List.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        End If
    Next ls
    ur.EndCustomRecord
End Sub
```

If you want the entire document content's font to be the one you want, then:

```vb
Sub Word_document_automatically_changes_font_in_number_list_All()
    Dim d As Document, ur As UndoRecord
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "Word_document_automatically_changes_font_in_number_list_All"
    
    'if d.Range.Font.Name<>"Roboto" then
    If d.Range.Font.Name <> "Calibri" Then
        'd.Range.Font.Name = "Roboto"
        d.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    End If

    ur.EndCustomRecord

End Sub
```

[image]

> ps. 模組 = module ; 物件 =  object ; 物件類別模組 = class module ; 表單 = user form